# How do you prevent the workflow file from being changed in feature branches? (Github Actions)

Tags: security, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

We have an organization (Github Team plan) and we're giving write access to developers so that they can create feature branches and merge into `main`.

From `main`, we're deploying to prod based on the branch name and a tag specified in our `.github/workflows/workflow.yaml` file.

I'm not sure how we can prevent a developer from changing the `workflow.yaml` file on a **feature branch**, changing the trigger to `on: push` and bypassing all checks and pushing straight to live from this branch (another thing could be said about leaking secrets).

Any ideas on how to do this? I know this feature is available in Github enterprise for private repos with "environment protected rules": https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/targeting-different-environments/using-environments-for-deployment#deployment-branches

While that answers my question, I'm wondering if there's another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken, you can specify the "Deployment branches" in "Environments", after all, the secrets are the ones that matter